# FFmpeg scaling issue

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to down scale a video from 607x1080 to 440 width with the height automatically being calculated using the following command. It does scale the video but not to the specified dimension. The video is scaled to 216x384 even though the output below indicates 440x384.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf scale=440:-2 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -y video-out.mp4
```

The output is as follows:

```
ffmpeg version N-87043-gf0f48884b0-static http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.4.0 (Debian 6.4.0-2) 20170724
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gray --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-librtmp --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      55. 74.100 / 55. 74.100
  libavcodec     57.103.100 / 57.103.100
  libavformat    57. 77.100 / 57. 77.100
  libavdevice    57.  7.101 / 57.  7.101
  libavfilter     6.100.100 /  6.100.100
  libswscale      4.  7.103 /  4.  7.103
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2017-12-13T19:49:15.000000Z
    encoder         : HandBrake 1.0.7 2017040900
  Duration: 00:00:04.37, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10080 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1238x1080 [SAR 27:55 DAR 619:1100], 10244 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-12-13T19:49:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 2 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-12-13T19:49:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : Stereo
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x5aef920] using SAR=1215/2474
[libx264 @ 0x5aef920] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x5aef920] profile High, level 2.2
[libx264 @ 0x5aef920] 264 - core 152 r19 ba24899 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'video-out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.77.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 440x384 [SAR 7428:15125 DAR 619:1100], q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-12-13T19:49:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.103.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-12-13T19:49:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : Stereo
      encoder         : Lavc57.103.100 aac
frame=  121 fps=0.0 q=29.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:04.33 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s speed=8.65x    
frame=  129 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     255kB time=00:00:04.37 bitrate= 478.0kbits/s speed=6.81x    
video:248kB audio:1kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.344491%
[libx264 @ 0x5aef920] frame I:1     Avg QP:22.07  size:  5065
[libx264 @ 0x5aef920] frame P:52    Avg QP:23.68  size:  4248
[libx264 @ 0x5aef920] frame B:76    Avg QP:24.30  size:   361
[libx264 @ 0x5aef920] consecutive B-frames: 12.4% 20.2% 20.9% 46.5%
[libx264 @ 0x5aef920] mb I  I16..4: 13.1% 81.7%  5.2%
[libx264 @ 0x5aef920] mb P  I16..4:  2.1%  5.2%  1.5%  P16..4: 36.4% 12.2%  8.2%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:34.4%
[libx264 @ 0x5aef920] mb B  I16..4:  0.2%  0.2%  0.1%  B16..8: 16.3%  1.3%  0.2%  direct: 0.5%  skip:81.2%  L0:42.2% L1:52.1% BI: 5.8%
[libx264 @ 0x5aef920] 8x8 transform intra:62.0% inter:70.3%
[libx264 @ 0x5aef920] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 52.3% 45.2% 20.0% inter: 13.3% 10.0% 2.6%
[libx264 @ 0x5aef920] i16 v,h,dc,p: 17% 48% 11% 24%
[libx264 @ 0x5aef920] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu:  8% 35% 23%  5%  3%  2%  6%  3% 14%
[libx264 @ 0x5aef920] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu:  8% 29% 16%  6%  7%  4% 12%  4% 14%
[libx264 @ 0x5aef920] i8c dc,h,v,p: 64% 26%  7%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x5aef920] Weighted P-Frames: Y:32.7% UV:5.8%
[libx264 @ 0x5aef920] ref P L0: 55.7% 22.1% 15.8%  5.8%  0.7%
[libx264 @ 0x5aef920] ref B L0: 77.8% 15.9%  6.3%
[libx264 @ 0x5aef920] ref B L1: 97.6%  2.4%
[libx264 @ 0x5aef920] kb/s:471.40
[aac @ 0x5b7e180] Qavg: 65536.000
```

I did some searching and learned this may be an issue scaling with libx264 codec and the input width being an odd number? If so, is there a workaround so get the video to scale to the specified size? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The scaling is "correct", but the video has a pixel or **s**ample **a**spect **r**atio below 1 (`27:55` ~= 0.491) so the video's effective display ratio is not the same as the ratio of width to height of the stored pixels.

Use the `-vf` expression below

```
-vf scale=440:2*trunc(ow/dar/2),setsar=1
```

Besides the scale, I reset the SAR to 1.

Comment: That works perfectly! Would the command also scale videos even if the SAR is not below 1 by just providing width and the code you provided for the height? I noticed that the command also worked for me if I did not apply 'setsar-1' as well. I like it where providing the width and height automatically calculated regardless if the SAR is below 1 or not. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the command will work for any SAR. The scale filter sets the SAR automatically. But due to rounding errors, it can be slightly off e.g. 0.999 hence the setsar.